# Disjoint, Convex Sets with No Strictly Separating Hyperplane

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning about the separating hyperplane theorem, which says that if C and D are nonempty, disjoint convex sets then there exist $a\neq 0$, and b such that $a^T x\le b,  \forall x \in C$ and $a^Tx\geq b,  \forall x \in D$. But can there exist two convex sets that are disjoint but cannot be strictly separated? I am struggling to come up with an example, but do believe it should be possible.

Comment: Simple parabolas example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E2+and+Plot+-(x+-+0.5)%5E2%2B0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: In $\Bbb R^2$ consider the sets

$$C=\{\langle x,y\rangle:x<0\}\cup\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$$

and

$$D=\{\langle x,y\rangle:x>0\}\cup\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}\;.$$

Comment: what if one of the sets is closed? And here is a relevant question I posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613690/separating-hyperplane-for-maximizers-of-a-convex-functional