# Separating hyperplane for maximizers of a convex functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, functional-inequalities

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of increasing uniformly bounded real functions on the closed unit interval, equipped with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx$.

Let $F:\mathcal{I}\to[0,1]$ be a continuous convex functional and $\mathcal{J}\subseteq \mathcal {I}$ be a convex and compact subset. Show that there is (a separating hyperplane) $g\in \mathcal{I}$ and $\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\langle g,x\rangle \leq\gamma$ for all $x\in \mathcal{J}$, and if the inequality holds with equality, then $x$ a maximizer of $F$ on $\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: This feels like there is something missing. What is the relationship between $\mathcal{J}$ and $F$?

Comment: There's no general relation. This is a more geometric version of what I am trying to show: Consider a {\em facet} of $\mathcal{J}$, there is a hyperplane that supports every point on the facet, but no other point of $\mathcal{J}$. (You can define a facet associated with a point $x_0\in\partial \mathcal{J}$ as the set of all points $x$ such that $x_0$ is a convex combination of $x$ and some other point of $\mathcal{J}$)

Comment: Are you assuming that $F$ is continuous?

Comment: I'm assuming $F$ is convex, doesn't that imply continuity here? (assuming continuity is okay in any case, and proving the geometric version is equivalently good)

Comment: No, it could be a discontinuous linear functional, of which there are lots...

Comment: I see, thanks, I updated and added continuity (although still not sure how it helps, because, if a maximizer of $F$ over $\mathcal{J}$  can be written as convex combination of two other points in $\mathcal{J}$, then those two points are also the maximizers of $F$, due to the convexity of $F$. And this is also the connection to the geometric version I wrote above)

Comment: I didn't spend much time on it, was just wondering if there must be a maximiser.

Comment: @copper.hat Here is a simpler question that I think implies an answer for my original question: Is a bounded convex functional always subdifferentiable? (or under what smoothness conditions it is)

Comment: Your simpler question is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575967/unbounded-subdifferential-of-a-convex-functional, I think.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I also found another reference (http://www.econ.ucla.edu/zame/goz3.pdf), in fact weaker conditions such as lower semicontinuity are sufficient for the existence of gradient. This resolves my question. I'll write a response to it later.